# Django - Custom name of a flash message

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-messages

I'd like to flash a message in a template, which there is a ton of information on, but I haven't seen any way to give it a custom name, which would allow it to have the appropriate class or id for styling.  In Laravel:

#### webpage.php

```
@if (session()->has('login_success'))
    <div id="loginFlash">{{ session('login_success') }}</div>
@endif
```

Where `login_success` is defined before rendering the page

So far with Django:

#### webpage.html

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div id="{{ message.tags }}">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But I can't get `message.tags` to return a SINGLE custom value.  For instance:

```
messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, self.request.user.username, 'loginFlash')
```

This returns:

```
<div id="loginFlash info">
    username
</div>
```

How to remove the second argument?  It seems like all of the `message` methods already specify at least one tag.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the `tags.messages` output to customise your own tags/classes per message category by overriding the setting for that level, like this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MESSAGE_TAGS

Answer (score 0):

Needs another if statement, but gets the job done:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'loginFlash' in message.tags %}
        <div id="loginFlash">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```